# How to retrieve data from 3 tables joined by a record identifier?

Tags: join, query

I have 3 tables.

I need to check whether a specific identifier is present in those tables using a specific `WHERE` condition. I need to fetch data from all 3 tables.

I have tried `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` but I couldn't get the values of the middle table.

My query attempt is:

```
Select t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
from t1
left outer join t2
on t1.id=t2.id
full outer join t3
on t1.id=t3.id
where t.id= '101';
```

I couldn't get the values which are present only in t2 table.

Comment: You do realise that your `WHERE` clause is searching for a table aliased as 't' but your tables are aliased 't1, t2 and t3'?
You should get an error with that query the way it currently is.

Comment: So you are trying to get all data from all three tables while matching related rows at the same time, correct?

Comment: yes im trying to get all the matching records

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that the ID column is either the PK or otherwise declared as unique in all three tables.

Now, if each of these scenarios is equally possible:

- all three tables have a row with the ID of 101,
- only two (any two) of the three tables have a row with the ID of 101,
- only one (any one) of the three tables has a row with the ID of 101,

and you want the requested data from every table that has a match – then you need to use only full joins.

This is one way how you could implement the request:

```
SELECT
  t1.Col AS t1Col,
  t2.Col AS t2Col,
  t3.Col AS t3Col
FROM
  t1
  FULL JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  FULL JOIN t3 ON COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) = t3.ID
WHERE
  COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID) = 101
;
```

As you can see, in order to match the third table's ID to that of either of the other two tables when only one of them has a match, you can use the COALESCE function. COALESCE will pick a non-empty (non-null) ID of the two specified, thus making sure that the third ID will be matched with an existing row in either table. The same condition will work correctly if the match is present in both tables.

The WHERE condition uses a similar technique for filtering the result set. Since each table's ID in every row of the joined set is supposed to be either the same value or a null, the COALESCE function will necessarily pick one that is not null to compare to the specified argument (101). Thus, only the row that has the matching data from all or any of the three tables will be selected.

You could also take a slightly different approach: separately select the row matching the `ID = 101` condition from each table, use the results as derived tables and then join them:

```
SELECT
  t1.Col AS t1Col,
  t2.Col AS t2Col,
  t3.Col AS t3Col
FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, Col FROM t1 WHERE ID = 101
  ) AS t1
  FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT ID, Col FROM t2 WHERE ID = 101
  ) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT ID, Col FROM t3 WHERE ID = 101
  ) AS t3 ON COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) = t3.ID
;
```

Although you now have to repeat the same filtering condition, the resulting query might turn out to be more efficient – that will depend on how smart the query optimiser is in your database system.

Test both queries to determine which works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have to retrieve which table has the most records and start your JOIN with that table and use LEFT JOIN
or you can do the opposite (search for the table with least records) and use RIGHT JOIN

and you have to set your tables with count of records
I mean if your tables have 1000 , 500 and 2000 records
you start the JOIN with the table with 2000 records Left JOIN the one with 1000 records and LEFT JOIN the one with 500 records